# Find $\sum_{k=0}^{n}4^k \binom{n}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Reading through my textbook I came across the following problem, and I am looking for some help solving it. In the back of the textbook they have shown the final answer but I'm not quite sure how to get there. If I could get some help that would be great, thanks!

Find, 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}4^k \binom{n}{k}$$

The solution given is,

$$C(7,1)C(4,1)+C(7,2)C(4,2)+C(7,3)C(4,3)+C(7,4)C(4,4)$$

Comment: Try n=0; the answer doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the expansion $(1+x)^n$ using binomial theorem. 
$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k \binom{n}{k}$$
Then substitute $x = 4$. That should lead you to the answer $5^n$.

Comment: thanks for the hint!

Comment: could you show me how this is done? this is my first attempt with the binomial theorem

Comment: Good observation  +1

Comment: @jh123 The binomial theorem states $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n x^ky^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}.$$Just let $x=4, y=1$. (The theorem itself can be proven with induction)

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^n 4^k1^{n-k}\binom{n}{k} $$

but then how do I use that to find the final solution? what is k?

Comment: $k$ is an index over which the sum is taken. By the binomial theorem, you know the expression you have is $(1+4)^n=?$

Comment: okay so, $$(1+4)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} 4^k \binom{n}{k}$$ but then how do I arrve at the answer $5^n$

Comment: Well, what is $1+4$?

Comment: 5 so all I have to write is $$(5)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} 4^k \binom{n}{k}$$